# Need XMLGregorianCalendar in specific time format| Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, zoneddatetime, xmlgregoriancalendar

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getXMLEventTime(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = null;

            if(zonedDateTime!=null) {

                GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
                gregorianCalendar.setTime(getDateFromZonedDateTime(zonedDateTime));
                xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
            }


        return xmlGregorianCalendar;
    }
```

I want to the output in "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517+00:00" format but got this "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517Z" as my server in in UTC.

When I run the application in my local (IST timeZone) I got the correct output "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517+05:30" but same not working in UTC timeZone

Comment: Why? `XMLGregorianCalendar` is specifically for handling XML date/time values, and the [XML Schema Data Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#dateTime) documentation specifically allows `Z`. Actually, the *canonical* format *is* `Z`, not `+00:00`, so `XMLGregorianCalendar` is correctly using the *canonical* format. It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I checked the source code. There is no way to make `XMLGregorianCalendar` not use `Z` for the zero offset. if you want `+00:00`, you can use an `OffsetDateTime` and a custom `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I’d like to challenge your title. What makes you think that you need an `XMLGregorianCalendar` in a specific format? An `XMLGregorianCalendar` hasn’t got a format, but prints in XML format when you call `toString()`. If it’s for an API, then the provider of the API should know that and should accept the `XMLGregorianCalendar` object that you pass to the API without worrying about “format”. If it’s for any other purpose, either the same consideration applies or the suggestion by @Andreas: *use an `OffsetDateTime` and a custom `DateTimeFormatter`*.

Comment: BTW, a bit easier: `GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(zonedDateTime);`

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. You also should not want to. As Andreas said in a comment, an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with UTC offset 0 necessarily prints with `Z`, not `+00:00`.

Suggestions:

1. Stop caring. Pass your `XMLGregorianCalendar` to wherever you need it, and I bet everything will be fine.
2. Let yourself inspire from the observation that it works fine with your local time zone. Just pick a non-zero offset from UTC, and you will get the format that you say that you want. For example:

   ```
       ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime
               .of(2020, 5, 6, 16, 58, 58, 517_000_000, ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
       zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
       GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(zonedDateTime);
       XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
               .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);

       System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar);
   ```

   Output:

   > 2020-05-06T17:58:58.517+01:00
3. As Andreas suggest in a comment, use a custom `DateTimeFormatter` to obtain a string (not an `XMLGregorianCalendar`) in the desired format:

   ```
       DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
               .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
               .appendPattern("xxx")
               .toFormatter();
       String formattedDateTime = zonedDateTime.format(formatter);

       System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
   ```

   > 2020-05-06T16:58:58.517+00:00

Answer (score 1):

I made the changes in XML object.

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar eventTime;
```

got the expected output.

I used XSD for message(XML) communication. after adding above DateTimeAdapter "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517Z" converted to "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517+00.00" Reference: [JAXB Date Format Example using Annotation | Java Date to XML DateTime String Conversion](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/jaxb-date-format-example-using-annotation-XMLAdapter.html)

Comment: above point mentioned by @Andreas is correct. 
I used XSD for message(XML) communication.  after adding above DateTimeAdapter 
"2020-05-06T16:58:38.517Z" converted to "2020-05-06T16:58:38.517+00.00"

Reference : https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/jaxb-date-format-example-using-annotation-XMLAdapter.html